# Mapping a MySQL server to Failover Cluster IP

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

I have successfully installed a two node cluster.

The problem I am having is mounting the MySQL service on the Cluster IP.
I am able to bind the service to the node IPs directly no problem.

If I tried to bind the install to the cluster name or IP on my specific port 56001 I get a conflict in the error logs saying;

2014-09-01 13:56:15 2116 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.1.200'; port: 56001
2014-09-01 13:56:15 2116 [Note]   - '192.168.1.200' resolves to '192.168.1.200';
2014-09-01 13:56:15 2116 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.1.200'.
2014-09-01 13:56:15 2116 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No error
2014-09-01 13:56:15 2116 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 56001 ?
2014-09-01 13:56:15 2116 [ERROR] Aborting

There is definitely no service already running.

If I bind to the name I get;

2014-09-01 14:32:53 2848 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): 'SLM_Internal'; port: 56001
2014-09-01 14:32:53 2848 [Note]   - 'SLM_Internal' resolves to '192.168.1.200';
2014-09-01 14:32:53 2848 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.1.200'.
2014-09-01 14:32:53 2848 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No error
2014-09-01 14:32:53 2848 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 56001 ?
2014-09-01 14:32:53 2848 [ERROR] Aborting

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the resolution.

At the bottom of the failover cluster manager, if you click on your role, at the bottom of the window you can select the IP address to bind the service too.

This seems to work.